# SaveChanges() for multiple dbcontext with TransactionScope in Entity Framework 4.1

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-4, asp.net-mvc-3-areas

I am using `SaveChanges()` method as given below:

`objAdbContext` of Database `A`

`objBdbContext` of Database `B`

Updating table of DB A as given below

```
public string SaveA()
{

//Some stuff

  objAdbContext.SaveChanges();

  string result=UpdateDatabaseB(some parameters)

  //Some stuff

}


public string UpdateDatabaseB(some parameters)

{

  //Some stuff

   objBdbContext.SaveChanges();

  return "Success";

}
```

This case Database B is not getting updated. Is it correct way of updating multiple databases?

Both are independent Databases and How to implement TransactionScope in this case?

Comment: Good formatting is your friend.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this:

```
using (TransactionScope scope = new TransactionScope())
{
    // Save changes but maintain context1 current state.
    context1.SaveChanges(SaveOptions.DetectChangesBeforeSave);

    // Save changes but maintain context2 current state.
    context2.SaveChanges(SaveOptions.DetectChangesBeforeSave);

    // Commit succeeded since we got here, then completes the transaction.
    scope.Complete();

    // Now it is safe to update context state.
    context1.AcceptAllChanges();
    context2.AcceptAllChanges();
}
```

This sample was taken from this blog post:

[Managing Transactions with Entity Framework 4](http://www.luisrocha.net/2011/08/managing-transactions-with-entity.html)

Comment: I believe SaveChanges(withParameter) doesn't exist in DbContext, only ObjectContext, they are different classes.