# C# EF Core call multiple SaveChangesAsync in Transactionscope throw timeout exception

Tags: c#, postgresql, entity-framework-core, transactionscope, savechanges

im really confused. When im calling multiple times SaveChangesAsync in a transactionscope the second SaveChangesAsync throw a database timeout exception.
**I need the transactionsscope because i have some operations between two different databases.**

I'm using Net 5.0 with EF-Core 5.0.10 and Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL 5.0.10

Hera is a very simple code snippet:

```
var transactionOptions = new TransactionOptions();
transactionOptions.IsolationLevel = IsolationLevel.ReadCommitted;
transactionOptions.Timeout = TransactionManager.MaximumTimeout;

using (TransactionScope scope = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.Required, transactionOptions, TransactionScopeAsyncFlowOption.Enabled))
{
      OrderItem item = await _unitOfWork.OrderItems.FirstOrDefaultAsync(x => x.Id.Equals("123456"));

      item.IsCanceled = true;
      await _unitOfWork.SaveChangesAsync();

      //some other code

      item.Qty = 0;
      await _unitOfWork.SaveChangesAsync(); // <--- Timeout Exception

      scope.Complete();
 }
```

_unitOfWork is coming from dependency injection and hold the DBContext

I also tried this with the same result -> timeout exception: [SaveChanges() for multiple dbcontext with TransactionScope in Entity Framework 4.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13875302/savechanges-for-multiple-dbcontext-with-transactionscope-in-entity-framework-4)

Have someone a solution for my problem?

Thanks!

**EDIT1:**

Without the second change on item -> `item.Qty = 0;`
I get no timeout exception.

Comment: To be clear, if you called the second `SaveChangesAsync()` first, does it succeed?

Comment: Hi @MarkC. , in my simple code snippet there only one database in use so it changes nothing in the result. Thanks for your help!

Comment: TransactionScope is introduced for distributed transactions, Also it’s implementation depends on Provider. I do not recommend to use them. Use ctx.BeginTransaction instead

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv It is possible to use ctx.BeginTransaction over two databases?

Comment: Well, my fault, if you need distributed transactions between databases, you need TransactionScope.

Comment: Can you show `_unitOfWork.SaveChangesAsync()`?